# Print divs in two columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a php application that generates data to a web page. The user then prints the document.

The data is divided into sections and each section is a div. The width of the div is fixed but the height can vary. I would like the printed output to be in two columns like so:

```
Page 1
---------------------
|  DIV 1  |  DIV 4  |
|---------|---------|
|  DIV 2  |  DIV 5  |
|         |---------|
|---------|  DIV 6  |
|  DIV 3  |         |
|         |         |
---------------------

Page 2
---------------------
|  DIV 7  |  DIV 10 |
|---------|---------|
|  DIV 8  |  DIV 11 |
|         |---------|
|---------|  DIV 12 |
|  DIV 9  |         |
|         |         |
---------------------

...and so on
```

Is this possible to do without having to hard-code the structure? Perhaps some javascript/jquery solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't guarantee with HTML/CSS that it will print correctly in all scenarios**, and you definitely don't want to go down the route of javascript to ensure correct printing (been there done that).

You're best bet is to dynamically create a PDF using a library such as [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).

Comment: Actually I've never used CSS print stylesheet. But isn't it a bit like CSS display stylesheet, with other words, you just have to check the popular browsers to see if it comes out ok, and perhaps apply a few "hacks"?

Comment: I found the problem is more along the lines of "I've got this new printer and it won't print correctly, the last one worked fine" so the issue is more printer/spooler software

Answer (score 2):

There's a jquery plugin called [Columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) that I've used before that's quite good and I think does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd be able to layout this page in pure CSS, that would be your solution:

http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml

The browser will use the stylesheet defined for printing, when it is printing your page.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the css `{column-count: 2;}` works once place in the print tag

Comment: What do you mean by "print tag"?